# How to resolve ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymatgen.analysis.defects'?

Tags: python, pymatgen

### Background

My goal is to use PyCDT: Python Charged Defect Toolkit ([paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cpc.2018.01.004), [github](https://github.com/mbkumar/pycdt), [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/pycdt/)). I installed the code by doing:

```
pip3 install pycdt
```

I am not using any virtual environment. The OS is Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. Python version: 3.10.12, pip version: 23.3.2.

### Issue

After installing the code, when I ran it, it gives the following error:

```
$ pycdt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pycdt", line 4, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').run_script('pycdt==2.0.5', 'pycdt')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 656, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1453, in run_script
    exec(code, namespace, namespace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pycdt-2.0.5-py3.10.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/pycdt", line 37, in <module>
    from pymatgen.analysis.defects.thermodynamics import DefectPhaseDiagram
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymatgen.analysis.defects'
```

### Attempt at solution

I have searched at the [PyCDT forum](https://groups.google.com/g/pycdt-forum) without success and also they are inactive in the forum for more than one and a half-year. I have tried installing it from the GitHub and their [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/mbkumar/pycdt/src) repo. After the seemingly successful installation, when I am running it, it throws an error saying:

```
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pymatgen==2020.6.8' distribution was not found and is required by pycdt
```

When trying to install that specific version of pymatgen, pip throws error saying `error: metadata-generation-failed`

Answer (score 1):

They break backwards compatibility all the time! I have run into different but equally frustrating problems before. It seems your problem may have solutions. See here: https://materialsproject.github.io/pymatgen-analysis-defects/intro.html